# Group processes by apps in Activity Monitor under Memory tab

Tags: google-chrome, activity-monitor, macos

I am using OSX 10.10.5 with activity monitor 10.10.0. Mac newbie.

In the memory tab, all the processes under chrome is scattered. I just want to know to how much of the resource is used by chrome all together. Is there a better app that will do it?

Basically, I want to see the resources used by all the apps that I using (seen on the side dock) grouped under the name of the apps.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but this feature does exist:
Go to Activity Monitor, click "View" (at the top) and select "All Processes, Hierarchically".

[image: group processes Hierarchically]

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Unfortunately even when in this grouped, it doesn't show sum of memory used by all sub threads