# In MacOS, how can I group the processes based on apps?

Tags: google-chrome, activity-monitor

I want to know the resources used on the basis of applications. I found a [duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202801/group-processes-by-apps-in-activity-monitor-under-memory-tab), but the answer there has issues and since its over a year old, I decided to post a new one, instead of posting there.

The solution in the previous post was, Activity Monitor>View>"All Processes, Hierarchically". But that has an issue:[image: The issue I am facing]

Did I do something wrong or is this a bug? Is there any other way of knowing it?

Answer (score 4):

These Google Chrome Helper processes are *sub-processes* of the Google Chrome app. You'll notice that the highlighted sub-process is indeed at the top of all the other sub-processes in the list - the proper hierarchy. You did nothing wrong, nor is there a bug.

Comment: I assumed that "Google Chrome" at the top, will show the sum total of all the processes under it. If you add up the rest, its will come upto a lot more than 108.5mb

Comment: The Google Chrome process _by itself_ uses 108.5 mb. It's memory allocation is for its own usage, not the sum total of itself and all its subprocesses. The subprocesses have their own memory allocations, and Chrome is designed to run this way so that if a process becomes hung, it won't _usually_ crash the whole app.

Comment: How can I know the total resources being consumed by Chrome along with all its subprocesses so that I can compare with firefox?

Comment: You'd have to manually add up all the mb listed for the Google Chrome and Google Chrome Helper processes that are running using a calculator. You might want to delve into the Terminal command `top` to extract the total memory used by Chrome and its helper subprocess.